# OSError: libedk.so cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory

Tags: python, shared-libraries, raspberry-pi, raspbian, ctype

I have these shared libraries libedk.so, libedk.so.1, libedk.so.1.0 and libedk.so.1.0.0, that are imported in my python file, when I run the module, I get this error "OSError: libedk.so: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory".
I am sure the libraries are linked, I put copies of them in /usr/lib, /usr/local/lib, and the same folder as my python file. Note: I tried putting the path of the libedk.so file as /usr/lib, /usr/local/lib and the directory of the python file still no luck. I am trying this on Rasbian (Debian) for Raspberry Pi, the same files are working on my 32bit Ubuntu.

I know there are similar questions, but the answers didnt help me.